# Access to the registry key is denied (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, dll

how can fix this error ? how can I access to the registry key ?
(this project is running on IIS server)
Access to the registry key 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ohadi\ODFSODFS' is denied.[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use the registry in a web-application?

Comment: i use dll file in project and it need that !

Comment: Why does that DLL need to access the registry then?

Comment: i did not wrote this dll file , i just use it ! i want to solve this problem !